# configuration for spring-data-mongo connection with replicaset + credential ( username & password )

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I am using spring-data-mongo version 1.6.0.RELEASE.
My spring-data-mongo configuration is like

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongoConnection" replica-set="${mongoDbReplicaSet}">
        <mongo:options socket-timeout="20000" />
</mongo:mongo>
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoConnection" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongoDbName}" />
</bean>
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.my.package.mongo.repository"
    mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate">
</mongo:repositories>
```

where
`mongoDbReplicaSet=172.229.226.221:17001,172.229.226.222:17001`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

mariadb-java-client-1.6.2.jar
mongo-java-driver-2.12.3.jar
```

I am looking for configration, how to use credential (username + password) in this configuration with spring-data-mongo version 1.6.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a mongo replicaset of 3 nodes(1 primary, 2 secondaries), with secutiry enabled (authentication required)

I am able to connect to mongo-replicaset with following spring configuration and able to read and write records to mongo-replicaset.

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" replica-set="localhost:27041,localhost:27042,localhost:27043"/>
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory"
                  mongo-ref="mongo"
                  dbname="testdb"
                  username="testuser"
                  password="testuserpass12"/>
<mongo:template db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory" id="mongoTemplate"/>
```

Spring-Data-Mongo version used is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```